# Fix css 3d perspective when height/content changes

Tags: css, 3d

This pen:
http://codepen.io/jeremytm/pen/KzOayw

How can I change the height of the box without affecting the perspective angle ?

For example, if you change the height, the top and bottom angles differ from the previous one.

I want the angles to stay the same, and only see a height increase.

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  if(document.getElementById('box').className==='bigger'){
    document.getElementById('box').className = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('box').className = 'bigger';
  }
},1000);
```

```css
#box {
  width:250px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height:200px;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000) rotateY(30deg);
  color: #6e1b0c;
}

#box.bigger {
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h1>I am a 3d Box</h1>
  <p>But! Change my height, and my perceived angle changes too!</p>
  <p>How do we fix this for dynamic heights?</p>
</div>
```

**Update**

Here is a video showing the problem in production. The first view is how I would like things to look, but as soon as we change to a new tab, the height changes, and so does the perspective.

**[Video](https://youtu.be/i9uGi7TN11I)**

Comment: question is not clear, what you r trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @Ajai Krishnan R Look at the box in the example. More specifically at the angle of the top of the box. Let's say it's at a 10 degree slope. Notice how it changes to a new angle just because the box gets bigger? I want to be able to make that box as high as I want, without that angle changing - otherwise if the box is too tall, the content becomes too skewed and unreadable. Does this help? If not I'll provide some screens of my actual project.

Comment: I have added a video in the original post which should explain things further.

Comment: chk the below answer @JeremyTM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've made some changes in CSS, instead of **rotateY** try **skewY**. Hope this will help you in some way.

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  if(document.getElementById('box').className==='bigger'){
    document.getElementById('box').className = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('box').className = 'bigger';
  }
},1000);
```

```css
 

#box { width:250px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      height:200px;
      background: tomato;
      padding: 40px;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1000) skewY(4deg);
      color: desaturate(darken(tomato,40%),20%);
    }
    #box h1, #box p {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1000) skewY(0deg);
      /*-webkit-transform: perspective(1000) skewY(-4deg);*/
    }
    #box.bigger {
      height:300px;
    }
    #box.bigger h1, #box.bigger p {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1000) skewY(0deg);
      /*-webkit-transform: perspective(1000) skewY(-4deg);*/
    }
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h1>I am a 3d Box</h1>
  <p>But! Change my height, and my perceived angle changes too!</p>
  <p>How do we fix this for dynamic heights?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much :)